# Redefine \section to be added to the index automatically

Tags: sectioning, indexing

I would like to have my section headers to be listed in the index by default. So i tried to redefine the `\section` command like this

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{#1}~\index{#1}}

\section{foo}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Unfortunaltely this destroys the index header and it looks like this:

[image: created index]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You are ignoring the `\section*` stuff, which isn't catched by this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\let\oldsection\section` and `\renewcommand{\section}{...}` carelessly will ignore the fact that `\section` is actually a command with moving arguments and the starred version, i.e. `\section*`.

The way used by the O.P. will then leave a stray `*` in the input and `\tableofcontents` (which uses `\section*{...}` will just print the `*`, as well as `\printindex`.)

I've used the easier way to redefine the `\section` command and taking care about the starred version and the optional argument. The `\index` command is inside of the section title automatically. `hyperref` might complain about that, however.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeindex


\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%  Is it the starred command? Yes, then no \index
    \oldsection*{#3}
  }{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{% Is it the optional argument version --> use #3
    \oldsection[#2]{#3\protect\index{#3}}
  }{%
    \oldsection{#3\protect\index{#3}} % Use #3 as well
  }
}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{foo}

\printindex

\end{document}
```